# How to rewrite simple callback with no returned value with reactive approach?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, android-livedata, observer-pattern

Let's say I want to rewrite a simple callback like `void updated()` with a reactive approach. The problem is Rx, LiveData, Flow "reactive tools" always ask for a name of a generic type. It makes sense, they work with stream of data and generic discloses type of this data. But! Is there a way to implement `void updated()` callback without returned type? For example rx callback `Observable<without type> updated()` from database. There is Completable in rx which doesnt need type, but it works only once and I want multiple. I can use `Observable<Object>` or `Observable<Event>` and return anything like `emitter.onNext("")` or `emitter.onNext(new Event())` but it looks dirty! Rx, Flow, LiveData has a lot in common (observer pattern at least) but they seem to me dont have such functionality. So either I dont know smth or I misunderstand the reactive approach or it is just not implemented. thx

Comment: How do you want multiple executions? Do you want to wait for individual `updated` calls or do you want to execute many of them and wait for all?

Comment: individual `updated` calls

Comment: I see. You either use `Completable` and recreate/subscribe to it over and over, or you create an `Observable<Object>` and just ignore the value ([example](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#nulls)).

Comment: Yes, `Observable<Object>` and `emitter.onNext(whatever)` works but I was hoping for something more beautiful. Something that can be called just like `emitter.onNext()`.

Comment: @akarnokd can I assume by your comment that the idea of having Observable, which doesn provide any data and just serves callback purpose, doesn't contradict any fundamental ideas of rx framework?

Comment: In theory, it is possible to derive such source. In practice, it adds a lot of maintenance and interoperation surface. It rarely comes up and developers just use `Observable<Object>`.